# Continuous images of compact sets are compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $Y$ any metric space.  If $f:X \to Y$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is compact (that is, continuous functions carry compact sets into compact sets).

**Proof**:

> Consider an open cover of $f(X)$.
>
> Then $f(X) \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}V_\alpha$ where each $V_\alpha$ is open in $Y$.
>
> $X \subset f^{-1}(f(X)) \subset f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}V_\alpha\right) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$.
>
> Hence $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ is an open cover of $X$.  Since $X$ is compact then we can choose a finite subcover $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $X \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(V_i)$.
>
> So then $f(X) \subset f\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(V_i)\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f\left(f^{-1}(V_i)\right) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$, a finite subcover of $f(X)$.  $\therefore f(X)$ is compact.

Does this proof have an error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don't write your titles in capital letters like this. It attracts attention, but not the good sort.

Comment: By "test" do you mean "proof?"

Comment: Where do you think there might be a mistake in the proof? ¿En dónde crees tú que existe un error en esa demostración?

Comment: @DonAntonio Perhaps you might be willing to invite him to post in Spanish, and then translate the question yourself? I and many others would much prefer well-translated intelligible questions to unintelligible questions, [as per this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la).

Comment: @Mark I think he's studying with a book in english as the language is pretty smooth (well, escept for the part he wrote by himself), but of course I wouldn't mind doing so.

Comment: The proof looks fine. Note that you never use the fact that these spaces are metric, so the first sentence could read, "Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, with $X$ compact."

Comment: The proof looks good.

Comment: so where did this proof use the fact that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The proof is not good. Knowing that $f$ is continuous does not say much about $f^{-1}$, while the proof assumes that it exists and is continuous. It was not given that $f$ is a homeomorphism.</s>

The statement is still true though. Take any sequence $x_n$ in compact $X$. Then it has a convergent subsequence $x_q$ (by definition of compactness). Now take the sequence $f(x_n)$ and notice that it has a convergent subsequence $f(x_q)$ (by definition of continuity). Since for any point $y \in f(X)$ there exists $x \in X $ such that $f(x) = y$, every sequence if $f(X)$ can be written as $f(x_n)$ for some sequence $x_n \in X$ and we are done.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is being used in [this sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image), I think.

Comment: You're right. I was worried about the pre-image of $f(x) = const.$, but that does work too.